# React App in S3 in Cloudfront distribution turning HTTPS request to HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm fairly noob and new to AWS, but I've been stuck on a bug.

I have a React App hosted as Static Website on A S3 Bucket with a Cloudfront distributions setup for it so it is secured with SSL. I also have a NodeJS/express Backend hosted on EC2 with a SSL certificate that I made myself and the EC2 is all set up to receive HTTPS request(I added a load balancer to handle HTTPS request).

Here is the twist. So basically in React project config, I have the Backend URL like this :https://long-url-to-ec2..... , you get the vibe.
So I basically have 2 environments, the React App in the S3 bucket (the unsecured app) and the React App in Cloudfront which is secured. But the problem is that in the S3 Bucket version of my app, all of my request are sent to https://my-backend but in the Cloudfront version, the request are only sent to http://my-backend . Cloudfront seems to not care about the URL and just send all of my request through HTTP even if https is specified in the URL!

Does anybody know what do I have to setup In Cloudfront so it sends my request to the good HTTPS URL and not just HTTP?

Comment: there is an option when creating a cloudfront " Redirect http to https"

Comment: Ive enabled it. But this is just for the front-end request from my browser. This does not affect the request that go from my React App to my Backend

Comment: how come you have two versions of React App? cloundfront only apears as a security layer for the s3 bucket, it does not contain the actual App.

Comment: I was was saying a have two URL to access my React App(The S3 link and the Cloudfront link)

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use the S3 url or the CloudFront url, it's the same React app which is hosted in S3. The issue is when your react app calls the backend, which is just an ALB url, correct? So it must be an issue with your react code. You define in your react app how you call the backend. It's got nothing to do with CloudFront.

Although I'm a bit confused how you could have different results when using the S3 url and the CloudFront url. Ultimately it's the exact same react app that calls the backend. You should start with the question of how you call the backend from your react app. The exact piece of code you're using. That should give you a clue.